# Windows password reset pogostick not working: kernel panic

Tags: windows, password-recovery

On my windows laptop I get the following message when trying to login:

"the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

According to Microsoft I should rejoin the domain - requiring a local admin account. But since, I do not know what local accounts are on the laptop I decided to use a password reset tool.

**So I downloaded a bootable USB image from [pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).
The boot process however fails with kernel panic:**

1. Booting … <many lines>
2. Decompressing Linux … Parsing ELF … done
3. **Kernel panic - not synching: No init found. Try passing init = option to** kernel

System: Lenovo T450s, CPU i5 5th generation.

**Any Idea how to fix it or what other tool works fine?**

Comment: To me it would seem an easier venture to ask someone for the local password instead. I'm also guessing that since this is a domain handshake failure, you're likely on a work laptop?

Comment: Yes I am on a work laptop. The company is very little and I am the administrator. And I would like to know a good password reset tool. Maybe a newer kernel could fix the problem.?

Comment: I used a tool probably even pogostick and it was very easy.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it will help other people in the same situation, but I hit this error when using the 2014-02-01 version (`cd140201.zip`) of ntpasswd (aka "Offline NT Password and Registry Editor"). I tried using an earlier version (`cd110511.zip`), and that worked for me.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too

Comment: I ran into `Kernel panic - not synching: No init found` when trying to boot from `cd140201.zip` on Dell T7910 (Windows 10 21H2) yesterday. Next, I tried `cd110511.zip` - although it booted OK, only USB drives were visible in chntpw. Neither HDDs, attached to the LSI SAS controller, nor NVMe SSDs were visible. The built-in driver installation fixed nothing. I suspect that that's a pretty high chance to run into "outdated drivers" issue with those pogostick images today, thus I'd [recommend](https://superuser.com/a/1747703/135260) to simply use chntpw from some alternative liveUSB image.

Answer (score 2):

I just [ran](https://superuser.com/questions/1097068/windows-password-reset-pogostick-not-working-kernel-panic/1747703#comment2711044_1309986) into the same issue yesterday, and ended up using `chntpw` from PartedMagic. Perfectly worked on my Windows 10 21H2, Dell T7910.

**Notes:**

1. [pogostick](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/) is an old bootable USB image with just `chntpw` tool inside. I assume that the only possible reason for anyone to want to boot pogostick is that they want to run `chntpw`. But `chntpw` is available on other liveCD/liveUSB distributions, that are easier to boot.
2. The pogostick seem to be quite outdated and no longer maintained. Today (2022-10-15), the most recent pogostick release is 2014-02-01.
3. The http://www.chntpw.com/download/ web page might look a bit more "modern", but it just offers the same files from [http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/) actually.
4. The [UBCD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) 5.3.9 contains an old (2013_08_10_i586) version of the [Parted Magic](https://partedmagic.com/) distro, and there's chntpw-110511 [inside](https://partedmagic.com/parted-magic-2013-08-10/). Newer Parted Magic versions would cost you ~[13USD](https://partedmagic.com/store/?currency=USD).
5. It could be a bit tricky to boot those outdated Parted Magic sometimes, but there's a number of pre-defined boot modes, and one of the "failsafe" modes always works for me up until now (which one depends on a particular hardware). Newer Parted Magic versions should be less tricky to boot.
6. Inside the graphical Parted Magic environment, there's a "Start -> System Tools -> Change Windows Password" tool, that [should](https://www.top-password.com/blog/reset-forgotten-windows-password-with-ultimate-boot-cd/), theoretically, run `chntpw`. However, it does not work for me - it was always unable to find my Windows installation. I ended up [using CLI](https://odzangba.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/reset-windows-administrator-password-with-chntpw/) instead.
7. Yesterday, I used Parted Magic 2022_01_18 (just because I had it at hand), *not* the UBCD 5.3.9 version (even though UBCD should have worked just as well, theoretically).